# Kinetic energy, heat, and temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature

What are the differences between heat, kinetic energy and temperature, and how are they all linked?

Comment: Well, there really is difference between heat and temperature (I don't know relationship between kinetic energy and temperature, except for ideal gases). This seems to me a valid, common question. I don't see any reason for this being closed.